# Usando Clone() en laravel

Tags: laravel-5, clone

estoy tratando de realizar una copia tanto de formato y contenido (un input y 2 select), 
para que al momento de apretar un botón, aparezcan ese mini formulario, por decirlo de algún modo abajo del original, eh investigado y me dicen que con el .clone de java se puede realizar, pero nose como ocupar alguien me puede orientar o ayudar?

CODIGO DE HTML

```html
<div id="divInsumos">
   <div id="formularioInsumo">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
          <label for="nameP" class="col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Insumo') }}</label>
       <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control input-lg select2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
           @foreach ($insumo as $Insumos)
              <option value="{{ $Insumos['id'] }}"> {{    $Insumos['nombreI'] }}</option>
           @endforeach
           </select>
        </div>
     </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <label for="nameP" class="col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Unidad de medida') }}</label>
            <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-lg select2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
               <option selected="selected">Seleccionar</option>
               <option>Kilogramo/s</option>
               <option>Litro/s</option>
               <option>Metro/s</option>
               <option>Unidad/es</option>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <label for="nameP" class="col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Cantidad') }}</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

BOTON PARA AGREGAR

```html
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4 .col-xs-offset-4">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="btnMas">MAS</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías agregar la librería jquery y después en el botón podrías hacer algo así:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4 .col-xs-offset-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="btnMas"
        onclick="$('#formularioInsumo').clone().appendTo('#divInsumos')">MAS</button>
</div>
```

Lo que hacemos ahí es buscar el div del formulario, clonarlo y agregarlo al primer div.

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!